# Sendgrid integration to frontend application

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I am trying to integrate sendgrid to my website. I was able to integrate the sendgrid and for now I am able to send mails. But I want to be able to edit templates before sending the mail. To describe more, I want to be able to extract templates onto my website and edit them in my compose screen or atleast preview them before being able to send the mails.

Is there a function in sendgrid which can help me do this or is there any other way which I can use to achieve it?